# HSSFWorkbook.write(FileOutputStream fileOut) not writing anything to the response stream

Tags: jsp, apache-poi, poi-hssf, hssf

Here is my code snippet

```
  try{

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=someName.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)0);

    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short)0);
    cell.setCellValue(1);


    row.createCell((short)1).setCellValue(1.2);
    row.createCell((short)2).setCellValue("Rajesh Kumar ");
    row.createCell((short)3).setCellValue(true);

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Excels/workbook.xls");
    wb.write(fileOut);

    fileOut.close();  
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The above snippet creates file successfully on hard disk. However whenever the excel sheet is opened it is blank ?

What is the reason ? What can be solution ?

Comment: Works fine for me with poi 3.9. Check trace for exceptions.

Comment: There are no exceptions

Comment: You appear to be writing the Excel Workbook to a file, not your response stream - is it as simple as that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the response's stream directly:

```
wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#write(java.io.OutputStream)) for the method says nothing about flushing the stream. Use `flush()` on `fileOut` before you `close()` it.

Comment: The documentation of FileOutputStream says nothing about it *having* a flush() method of its own.

Comment: err... It inherits the `flush()` method from an [OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). It is unclear if the OP wanted to write to a local stream on the server or a response stream. Either way without flushing the stream, it wont work.

Comment: You don't have to flush streams before you close them. Close calls flush.

Answer (score -1):

> HSSFWorkbook.write(FileOutputStream fileOut) not writing anything to the response stream

Correct. It writes to the FileOutputStream you gave it.

If you want it to write to the response output stream, give it the response output stream to write to.